# Is There Any Automated Code Review Tool/Service for Matlab?

Tags: code-analysis, code-review, matlab

I am looking for a service (or tool) like Codacy or any other popular automated code review tool supporting Matlab. Is there anyone knows one?

I want to use it in git workflow. I need it to be triggered automatically after every pull request (like Codacy and similar other products do) so every commit in team can be reviewed automatically.

I prefer a hosted service but if necessary I can host it on my server too.

Comment: Does the Code Analyzer already built into the MATLAB editor not work for you? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html#brqxeeu-156

Comment: It is nice but I want an integration to git workflow. What I really want is to have automated code review for every pull request. Is it possible with code analyzer? @EricShain

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps you should add some more detail about desired features in your question.

Comment: MATLAB is a proprietary commercial product so it is rather unlikely you are going to find what you are looking for. If you have a legitimate license, I'd call Mathworks and ask about Code Analyzer's capabilities with git. They have really good tech support.

Comment: According to this link, MATLAB has git integration: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-git-source-control.html

Comment: @EricShain I will try asking to MathWorks, good idea. And you are right probably there is no service like this for Matlab. But I wanted to be sure by asking here.

Comment: Do you need a hosted service? Would a server that you install on one of your machines (with a Matlab installed) be OK?

Comment: I prefer a hosted service, but if necessary I can host it on my server and configure too (as I don't have much option, it seems). @NicolasRaoul